Computer keeps shutting down, as though it's hibernating, but neither hibernate or suspend are enabled
I have my computer, running 22.04, set to blank the screen after 15 minutes, and that works fine during the day, but when I leave my computer on overnight, it has recently started to shut down, but shuts down as though it is hibernating, since it will come up if I press a key on the keyboard.  When it comes up though, it's as if it were shut down, as nothing I had open is open.
This is not just that my computer shuts down either, because I don't have the setting to wake on USB enabled in the bios, and if I manually shut the computer down, it doesn't wake when I press a key.
I have no swap partition, so I shouldn't be able to hibernate.  I don't have it even set to suspend, just blank the screen.
It just started doing this about a week ago, and I'm at a loss to figure out what's causing it.  I have made no hardware changes.  I don't think I've even installed any new software in that time, other than updates.
Any ideas what could be causing this, and how to stop it?

there are a couple of earlier Q&A's with perhaps useful comments to explore - here and here too
